# Cannot disable classList changes

Tags: javascript, dom-events, hover, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

I have a couple of links that change their color upon hover. They have 'lang-switcher' class. Here's the code of one of them (they are identical):

```
<div class="header__lang-container _flex-column-center nav__item-container">
                    <a href="" class="nav__simple-link header__lang lang-switcher">eng</a>
                    <ul class="lang-container">
                        <li><a href="" data-lang="eng" class="lang-container__eng lang-container__item">eng</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" data-lang="ukr" class="lang-container__ukr lang-container__item">ukr</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Here's their styling. Notice ._is-active-simple-link selector that causes the problem:

```
._is-active-simple-link {
    color: rgb(194, 190, 190);
}
    .nav__simple-link {
    transition: color .3s;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

What I am trying to do is disable toggling this class after I click the link (leaving the link active), and when I click this link again, hovering effects should be enabled again, but for some reason this doesn't work.

```
const lang_switchers = document.querySelectorAll('.lang-switcher');
let isSwitcherOpen = false;
lang_switchers.forEach(elem => {
        elem.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if(!isSwitcherOpen) {
                hoveredLink();
                makeLinkInactive();
            }
            else {
                unhoveredLink();
                makeLinkActive();
            }
            isSwitcherOpen = !isSwitcherOpen;
        });

        makeLinkActive();

        function makeLinkActive() {
            elem.addEventListener('mouseover', hoveredLink);
            elem.addEventListener('mouseout', unhoveredLink);
        }

        function makeLinkInactive() {
            elem.removeEventListener('mouseover', hoveredLink);
            elem.removeEventListener('mouseout', unhoveredLink);
        }

        function hoveredLink() {
            elem.classList.add('_is-active-simple-link');
        }

        function unhoveredLink() {
            elem.classList.remove('_is-active-simple-link');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your mouseover event is not working

try this :

Now the hovering effects should be enabled again

```
const lang_switchers = document.querySelectorAll('.lang-switcher');
var isSwitcherOpen = false;
lang_switchers.forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!isSwitcherOpen) {
            hoveredLink();
            makeLinkInactive();
        }
        else {
            unhoveredLink();
            makeLinkActive();
        }
    });

    window.addEventListener('mouseover',()=>{
        elem.classList.remove('_is-active-simple-link');
    });

    function hoveredLink() {
        elem.classList.add('_is-active-simple-link');
    }

    function unhoveredLink() {
        elem.classList.remove('_is-active-simple-link');
    }
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).